# Installation Ubuntu in text mode

Tags: system-installation, text-mode

How to install Ubuntu 13.10 in text mode? Alternate ISO is discontinued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the server version and then when you finish install manually ubuntu-desktop package. The result will be almost the same as installing the default Ubuntu.